# MassTransit: Additional error raised when consumer has an exception. "The IErrorTransport was not available on the ReceiveContext."

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, masstransit

I have some consumers that runs in an Azure Function that has been upgraded to MT 6.0.2 and Azure Functions 3 and core 3. When an error is encountered in the consumer the message is not sent to the error queue and the following error is logged.

> The IErrorTransport was not available on the ReceiveContext.

This is my function method. Am I missing something on configuring the receiver?

```
        public async Task ExecuteMessageConsumerAsync(
            [ServiceBusTrigger(CoreEndpoint.InputQueue)] Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message message,
            IBinder binder,
            ILogger log,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            LogContext.ConfigureCurrentLogContext(log);

            LogContext.Info?.Log("Creating brokered message receiver");

            await ContainerContext.ExecuteAsync(scope =>
            {
                var handler = Bus.Factory.CreateBrokeredMessageReceiver(binder, cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.CancellationToken = cancellationToken;
                    cfg.InputAddress = _endpoint.InputQueueAddress;

                    cfg.UseInMemoryOutbox();
                    cfg.UseServiceBusMessageScheduler();
                    cfg.UseMessageRetry(r  =>
                    {
                        r.Intervals(10, 100, 500, 1000);
                        r.Ignore<ApplicationException>();
                    });

                    cfg.ConfigureSend(x => x.UseTenantContext<int>(scope));
                    cfg.ConfigurePublish(x => x.UseTenantContext<int>(scope));

                    // Command consumers
                    cfg.Consumer<EmailCallbackConsumer>(scope, "message", (c, consume) => c.UseTenantContext<int>(consume));
                });

                return handler.Handle(message);
            });
        }
```

After upgrading to 6.1.

````
 ---> MassTransit.TransportException: sb://no-host-configured/no-queue-specified => The IErrorTransport was not available on the ReceiveContext.
   at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ErrorTransportFilter.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ExceptionReceiveContext>.Send(ExceptionReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next)
   at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.GenerateFaultFilter.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ExceptionReceiveContext>.Send(ExceptionReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next)
   at GreenPipes.Filters.RescueFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)
   at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.DeadLetterFilter.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ReceiveContext>.Send(ReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next)
   at MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Transport.BrokeredMessageReceiver.MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Transport.IBrokeredMessageReceiver.Handle(Message message, Action`1 contextCallback)
   at MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Transport.BrokeredMessageReceiver.MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Transport.IBrokeredMessageReceiver.Handle(Message message, Action`1 contextCallback)
   at Symend.Core.App.AzureFunctions.Functions.ExecuteMessageConsumerAsync(Message message, IBinder binder, ILogger log, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\src\Core\Symend.Core.App.AzureFunctions\Functions.cs:line 53
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidTaskMethodInvoker`2.InvokeAsync(TReflected instance, Object[] arguments) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\VoidTaskMethodInvoker.cs:line 20
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync(Object instance, Object[] arguments) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs:line 52
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource, CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource, Boolean throwOnTimeout, TimeSpan timerInterval, IFunctionInstance instance) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 585
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, ILogger logger, CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 532
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, IFunctionOutputDefinition outputDefinition, ILogger logger, CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 468
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance, FunctionStartedMessage message, FunctionInstanceLogEntry instanceLogEntry, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 278
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.MessageProcessor.CompleteProcessingMessageAsync(Message message, FunctionResult result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.Listeners.ServiceBusListener.ProcessMessageAsync(Message message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageReceivePump.MessageDispatchTask(Message message)```
````

Comment: Related [issue](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/1683) (resolved).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an Azure Function with the latest -develop packages (which will be released as 6.1), messages that fault will not be moved to an *_error* queue, and will instead throw an exception so that Azure can move that message to the dead letter queue. There was an issue in 6.0.1, and a subsequent issue in 6.0.2 (related to IDeadLetterTransport).

Try the latest packages (-develop) and let me know if that fixes the issue. Otherwise, there may be yet another bug hiding in there.

Comment: I upgraded to 6.1 and I still seem to be getting the same error when consumer error is raised. Would you like me to post my information on github, so you can investigate?

Comment: Yes, create an issue. I think I see why, and am looking at how that can be resolved.